# How to clone a Select2 element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

How to clone a Select2 element?

https://jsfiddle.net/yhxtLqq6/

```
var clone = $('.select').clone();
$('body').append(clone);
```

It doesn't work properly...

Comment: Please look at the marked duplicate at the use of `destroy` i.e: `$(".select").select2("destroy");`. Ones destroyed, clone the element and **re-initilize** the select2 `$('.select').select2({....})` - You should check the documentation on `select2` to see how it works and inspect the DOM so you know what it does.

Comment: You would need to destroy and recreate the select 2: https://jsfiddle.net/yhxtLqq6/54/